# How to bind special character constant value inside xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, azure-logic-apps

I have created xslt which i use inside logic app.
inside xslt file i have set constant variable with value which contain special character `Eräpäivä`

But after process `logic app` it is showing data as `ErÃ¤pÃ¤ivÃ¤`

input xml -

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
                     <demo>
                     <Mynode name=\"Date\">2018-03-10T12:00:00-12:00</Mynode>
                     <Mynode name=\"Money\">EUR</Mynode>
                     <Mynode name=\"Goal\">PI</Mynode>
                    </demo>
```

transform xslt code-

```
                <xsl:for-each select="../../demo">
                <xsl:variable name="var:v28" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string(@name) , &quot;Date&quot;)" />
                <xsl:if test="string($var:v28)='true'">
                    <mydata>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$var:v3" />
                    </mydata>
                </xsl:if>

               </xsl:for-each>
```

But after execution value is coming `<mydata>ErÃ¤pÃ¤ivÃ¤</mydata>`
`expected output is <mydata>Eräpäivä</mydata>`  which is originaly set into xslt.

[image]

Comment: You are saving your XSLT stylesheet as UTF-8, but you are not *loading* it as UTF-8.

Comment: whats the probable solution if you can guide me ? how to set this constant value so that after transformation also it comes as it is original ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the code that loads the XSLT, the bug is in there. Show the code if you can't see the problem.

Comment: @Tomalak updated all in detail pls guide. Thanks

Comment: Hm, I see... There's not a lot you can configure, is there? Double-check that your XSLT is saved correctly: Set your editor to UTF-8 and place the full the XML declaraction at the top of the XSLT file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` Try the transformation on your local computer first to make sure it does the right thing. You can use the [msxsl.exe command line utility](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) for such tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are seeing is what you get if the data at some stage was written in UTF-8 encoding, but read by something that thought it was encoded in iso 8859-1 (or windows cp1252). The challenge is to find out where the mistake occurred. It could be:

- the data is already wrong in the stylesheet file.
- the stylesheet file is correct utf-8, but the parser is misreading it as 8859-1.
- the output of the stylesheet is correct utf-8, but the software displaying the output is under the impression it is 8859-1.

My next stage in investigating the issue would therefore be to examine the stored XSLT and result files using a hex editor to see how the characters are actually encoded.

Comment: for input fie data it is passed to next level , thanks a lot for your guidance :)